# Why the code in my answer is not color-highlighted?

Tags: support, color, code-block

This is [the question](https://serverfault.com/questions/300888/how-is-io-6-9001jiaiua121698aa-too-simplistic-systematic/300893) I'm referring to: the answer I provided contains some valid C code.
It is intended with 8 space chars.
The code is not colored as it does usually (at least on stackoverflow).

Did something change - or SF does not provide coloring like SO does?

Comment: For the record I believe I was one of the first asking for this to be turned off.  Highlighting is generally more broken here then useful.  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/883/is-the-syntax-highlighting-for-code-blocks-useful-on-sf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the question had been tagged [c](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/c), your code block would have worked. But, it wasn't.

You could *add* the tag, I suppose... But that seems lame, since the question wasn't *about* C.

So your next best option is to simply [force syntax highlighting for your code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify), by prefixing it with a special comment:

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

    ... code goes here, indented by four spaces as usual ...
```

I've done this for you. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks... The desperately unexpected answer!

Answer (score 2):

We turned off code-coloring because text enclosed in code brackets here is so very rarely something SO has a dissector for. Things like umpty lines of syslog entries, random java stack-dumps in application-specific log-files, or RFC quotations don't react well to syntax-coloring for most programming languages. We have a few tags where they're turned on, [powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell) is one such I believe, but in general we don't syntax-color here.

Comment: That sounds like a wise decision. But you should have a way to force color highlighting. (e.g. using the <code> tag - that I tried also)

Comment: I was going to say that [you could](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify), but I just tried a test post here on meta and it doesn't seem to permit you even if you explicitly request it.

Comment: @Zoredache: meta doesn't have *any* syntax highlighting enabled. The main site does. Your test would have worked on the main site...

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting of programming languages really doesn't make a whole lot of sense on a non-programming site. SF is not SO, so don't expect things to work identically.