# Vote: Do we want code highlighting?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, code-block, poll

Currently, code highlighting is turned off (see [balpha](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/14041/balpha)'s comment [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2672/syntax-highlighting-based-on-tag/2673#2673)). It is possible to turn it on, if we want so.

I think this would be nice to have, maybe on a per-tag basis, but turning it on is definitely the first step.

Because it is disabled site-wide, we can't force it by manually specifying the language as [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971/160455).

**Caution**: This vote is not about wether or not we should enable it automatically when a certain tag is used, it's wether or not we should enable code highlighting on the site.

Upvote the according answer below.

**Update**: I think it's pretty clear where this is going. Can anyone do this change?

Comment: Does the prettifier support the languages we would expect to see here? Such as powershell/bash/cmd/vbscript?

Comment: btw, if I want code highlighting, but *only if it's explicit turned on* (with the <!-- --> syntax), should I add a 3rd option, or vote for "yes"?

Comment: Vote Yes. We will get to the tags-thing later ;). Almost all languages are in the prettifier. Powershell = C#, rest of them are there.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Totally agree, I'm only voting yes to get that option, do not want automatic anything. =]

Comment: @MarkHenderson (or anyone else who has used the highlighting features on other sites) -- Is there an equivalent `<!-- stop highlighting my file you're doing it wrong! -->` tag?

Comment: @voretaq7, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting.  The answer seems to be `<!-- language: lang-none -->`.

Comment: @Zoredache disgusting, but acceptable.  I have no objection to syntax highlighting as long as we can make it stop if it's screwing up :)

Comment: @voretaq7 Or if it's off by default and needs to be manually turned on with the html comment?

Comment: @ShaneMadden also acceptable.  I'd like stuff like shell scripts to get auto-highlighted, but if it's a choice between "On by default and has to be turned off" or "off by default and has to be turned on" I'd prefer off by default.

Comment: @voretaq7 Indeed - and non-insane coloring for some of the common config file types we see would be a nice wishlist item.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Most of this would of course be moot if people ***INDENTED THEIR {CODE, CONFIG FILES}*** :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, I want code highlighting.

---

This has been enabled, and at this time these tags inherited syntax highlighting and have it enabled.

[vb](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vb)
[vbscript](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vbscript)
[perl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/perl)
[vb.net](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vb.net)
[powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell)
[bash](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bash)
[sh](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sh)
[shell-scripting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting)

---

The tags below have inherited code highlighting but it is off by default.

[oracle](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
[mysql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mysql)
[delphi](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/delphi)
[json](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/json)
[haskell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/haskell)
[netbeans](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/netbeans)
[drupal-6](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6)
[asp.net-mvc-2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-2)
[boost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/boost)
[drupal](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/drupal)
[ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ios)
[postgresql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)
[php](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php)
[qt](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/qt)
[.net-2.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/.net-2.0)
[gcc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gcc)
[.net-4.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0)
[stored-procedures](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedures)
[soap](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soap)
[jsp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jsp)
[asp.net-mvc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)
[servlets](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/servlets)
[asp.net-ajax](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-ajax)
[asp-classic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic)
[c++](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
[html5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/html5)
[lua](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lua)
[ajax](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ajax)
[jquery](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jquery)
[codeigniter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter)
[sql-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)
[sql-server-2005](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005)
[tsql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tsql)
[sql-server-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008)
[c](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/c)
[j2ee](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/j2ee)
[sqlite](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sqlite)
[php5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php5)
[ant](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ant)
[wordpress](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)
[cakephp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cakephp)
[flash](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/flash)
[xml](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/xml)
[zend-framework](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework)
[css](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/css)
[ruby-on-rails](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)
[c#](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
[hibernate](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hibernate)
[django](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/django)
[ruby](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ruby)
[javascript](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
[html](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/html)
[coldfusion](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion)
[android](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/android)
[regex](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/regex)
[vb6](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vb6)
[wcf](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wcf)
[sharepoint](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint)
[http](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http)
[python](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/python)
[sql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sql)
[database](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/database)
[java](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/java)
[asp.net](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)
[.net](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/.net)
[plsql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/plsql)
[mono](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mono)
[jboss](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jboss)

Moderators can configure (include turning highlighting off) syntax highlighting for a tag on the tag info page.

Comment: Someone downvoted this option -_-' Be sure to only count the upvotes please.

Comment: Looks like the consensus is "turn it on", so it's been turned on.  Moderators can now configure which tags get syntax highlighting, 74 tags are already configured for it.

Comment: Ok, can one of our mods get some serious mass-disable going on the tag set?  A ton of these tags are non-applicable, and there's some [strange results](http://serverfault.com/a/356879/72586).

Comment: @ShaneMadden: That was caused by the iphone tag having default code highlighting.

Comment: @Iain Yup, and we don't get a lot of Objective-C questions here - a small handful of auto-highlighted tags might make sense (database tags, scripting language tags), but for the most part I think we'll need to stick with manual.

Comment: Indeed. Manual looks like the best for now. Thanks @KevinMontrose!

Comment: Either I am getting colorblind or the [code highlighting](http://serverfault.com/questions/353888) does not deserve its name - the changes in color nuances on keywords are marginal and hardly distinguishable (at least on my screen). Are there personal settings to change the color scheme for highlighting?

Comment: @Iain Mind turning it off for the `ios` tag, too?  It means a [different thing here than it does on SO](http://serverfault.com/q/357392/72586).

Comment: @syneticon-dj The repainting of our CSS is a subject for a future debate.  I DEMAND EVERYTHING BE POLKA-DOTTED!

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't want code highlighting.

Comment: I think I initial submitted the request to have it disabled.  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/883/is-the-syntax-highlighting-for-code-blocks-useful-on-sf  I think it was more annoying then useful.

Comment: @Zordache This was back in 2010, when there was no option to manually choose it, it was always tied to a tag. This is no longer true. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971. This vote is not about tying it to a tag and making it automatic, only to make it possible to do a manual override.

Comment: @Zoredache: Asked it over at m.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120089/how-does-the-code-highlighting-feature-work I think we can be certain that if no tags are tied to a language, nothing will happen. **The behavior of this feature has changed since we asked to disable it**