# Vote: What level of automatic code highlighting do we want?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, code-block, poll

Now that have [code highlighting enabled](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2717/vote-do-we-want-code-highlighting), we need to determine how 'automatic' it should be.

The code highlighting engine works in two ways:

1. Automatic inference of the language in use via the tags on the question, and
2. Manual specification of the language in a code block, overriding any language behavior on a question tag

Currently, we have highlighting enabled for a [large number of tags](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/2718/72586), a default set from Stack Overflow or some such.  We've already disabled automatic highlighting on a small handful ([ios](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ios), [iphone](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iphone), [php](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php)) due to awkward highlighting on questions, but we need to decide what approach to take for a consistent behavior across all tags.

Comment: Whichever route we go we should try to find somewhere more prominent than the m.SO post for explaining how to turn on (or OFF) the highlighting...

Comment: It's there, just buried at the bottom of the page: http://serverfault.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting (fixed the link in the answer)

Comment: I was more referring to the list-o-languages, though this is pretty obscure too :)

Comment: Please, only use the up votes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Enable it extremely selectively on tags where the content of a code block has a high chance of actually being code.

For instance, enable these:

- `lang-sh` - [bash](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bash) [sh](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sh) [shell-scripting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting)
- `lang-vb` - [vbscript](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vbscript)

But, leave most everything else disabled.

- Our [mysql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mysql) [postgresql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) [sql-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) questions should be more configuration and errors than SQL syntax; `lang-sql` would be more detrimental then helpful.
- Our [python](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/python) [django](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/django) questions are rarely code, and rarely even stack traces; `lang-py` would be more detrimental than helpful.
- Our [php](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php) [php5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php5) questions are rarely code, `lang-php` would be more detrimental than helpful.
- ...etc...

Comment: This answer has been implemented with the addition of [tag:perl],[tag:vb].[tag:vb.net],[tag:powershell]

Answer (score 6):

### Disable all automatic highlighting, globally, across all tags.

You won't see a lot of highlighting at all, since it needs to be manually specified by the author (it's explained in [editing help](https://serverfault.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), but to really do it right takes a [dig in m.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/167585)) - but at least there won't be any highlighting of something that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

### Enable it on all tags for which there's a language available, even if we get some false-positive highlighting.

The increased incidence of highlighting on actual code is worth it, and/or the coloring is subtle enough that it doesn't bother me.

Comment: FTFY​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @MarkHenderson Thanks :)