# Broken highlighting. ruby-on-rails

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

This question [Problems installing Gitorious on Debian 6.0.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/356500/problems-installing-gitorious-on-debian-6-0-4) has broken highlighting.  It appears to because of the [ruby-on-rails](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) tag.

I semi-randomly looked at a couple dozen questions in that tag, and the vast majority of the code blocks all seem to be web server configuration files, or log files.  There is very few code samples that I could see in the dozen or so questions I looked at.

Should highlighting be enabled here?

Answer (score 5):

There's no "ruby" highlighting. The tag is set to use "default". As you've pointed out it seems broken. I'm going to turn it off unless someone can come up with a great reason it should be on.

Comment: Off is better than on

Comment: Maybe call [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/2898/72586) a consensus and purge a lot of the default highlights?