# What's going on with syntax highlighting?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighting in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/371460/serve-empty-404-page-with-mod-rewrite) seems to have matched a slash as being the start of a comment (or maybe a Perl-style regex) and kept that colour until it encountered another slash.

Is it not detecting the correct type of syntax highlighting to apply or does the Apache config highlighting care about slashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that syntax highlighting was enabled for [drupal](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/drupal) and it was misinterpreting the mod_rewrite syntax as drupal syntax. I've turned it off.

Comment: I wonder if we could find a list of the tags that have highlighting turned on so we can review it...

Comment: @ChrisS: the list is [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/2718/9517). I've split it into two groups enabled by default and disabled by default.

Comment: *Ahem*: http://meta.serverfault.com/q/2898